# ¿Qué significa el resultado de apachectl status?

Tags: linux, apache

Tengo un servidor Linux. Cuando ejecuto apachectl status en la consola, aparecen varias líneas como resultado. Las primeras dos líneas son estas:

```
* httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```

¿Me ayudan a entender qué exactamente significa cada parte mencionada en la 2da línea?

Entiendo que la 2da línea dice que Apache está cargado (loaded), o sea que está arriba y funcionando. Pero no sé qué quiere decir el **enabled** que aparece ahí, ni qué significa el **vendor preset: disabled**.

Gracias!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas el comando, las líneas que te aparecen indican el estado del servicio:

- **Loaded**: Como bien decías indica que el servicio está levantado.
- **Enabled**: Indica que el servicio esta activado y que el sistema garantiza que se va a seguir ejecutando mientras el sistema este levantado, es decir, si se cae el servicio se volverá a levantar a no ser que se reinicie la máquina.
- **Vendor preset**: Si está habilitado quiere decir que si el sistema se reinicia, el servicio se va a levantar de forma automática. Si está deshabilitado como en tu caso y la máquina se reinicia, el servicio no se va a levantar automáticamente.

Los comandos para habilitar/deshabilitar estas funciones son las siguientes:

- Iniciar apache como servicio, es decir, levanta apache y también lo pone como **enabled**:

```
apachectl start
```

- Parar apache:

```
apachectl stop
```

- Habilitar **vendor preset**:

```
apachectl enable
```

- Deshabilitar:

```
apachectl disable
```

- Recargar Apache por si se modifica la configuración:

```
apachectl reload
```

- Comprobar estado:

```
apachectl reload
```

En sistemas como Centos, Ubuntu, etc que utilizan systemd los comandos son difirentes, por ejemplo:

```
systemctl start apache2
```

En esta página viene bien explicado: https://www.sololinux.es/iniciar-detener-reiniciar-habilitar-y-deshabilitar-apache-en-linux/

Comment: Excelente! Ahora, @dgrana, ¿será posible que puedas extender un poco tu valiosa respuesta e indicar cuáles son los comandos para poner enabled/disabled esas dos funciones que acabas de clarificar?

Comment: @BerkeleyNow ahí lo tienes ;)

Comment: @BerkeleyNow, ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!